# Copy iTunes playlists to pen drive for car

Tags: usb-flash-drive, itunes, macbook-pro

I want to transfer my iPhone playlists from a MacBook Pro to a flash drive for use in the car.

However, when I select "export" it just exports a "txt" file. How can I export the playlist properly into the flash drive?

Answer (score 1):

A playlist isn't going to help you for that, I'm afraid. iTunes uses absolute references for where the files are stored, so you'd have to also export the files themselves to the USB drive & change the references to match - that's if the player will even recognise the playlist format.

Long & short of it is, Apple don't want you just dropping files here & there, they want you to use an iPod etc.

First couple of lines of an export below. New line & Tabs appear to be the only extra data.

```
'Name   Artist  Composer    Album   Grouping    Genre   Size    Time    Disc Number Disc Count  Track Number    Track Count Year    Date Modified   Date Added  Bit Rate    Sample Rate Volume Adjustment   Kind    Equaliser   Comments    Plays   Last Played Skips   Last Skipped    My Rating   Location
Weightless 2010 remix   Norton Disney       Less        Indie   8765956 219         1       2006    22/05/2014 08:38    17/09/2010 17:44    320 44100       MPEG audio file         1   30/12/2010 13:35                OhDaSpace:iTunes_Remote:Music:Norton Disney:Less:Weightless 2010 remix.mp3'
```

Comment: I am pretty sure an iTunes playlist is just XML but you are correct the references are absolute file paths.

Comment: You'd wish;-) but actually it really does just look like 'text'- I'll post a couple of lines in an edit, cos it won't work in comments.

Comment: Clarification - the library is, of course, an XML - I've spent many a happy hour porting the same library from one machine to another, using a shared remote file location

Comment: I had to deal with fixing a AirPlay problem recently, I thought it was XML, might have been something else that was XML.  Your point remains true.  The car's device would need to support reading this file format.